# Shape of passed values is (492, 7), indices imply (1, 7) for financial data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

```
dxy='https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=DXY&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&format=JSON&dp=3&start_date=2019-07-21%2011:42:00&end_date=2021-06-21%2011:42:00&previous_close=true&apikey=7477d5d3af13461b8896af80623bb808'
spx='https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=SPX&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&format=JSON&dp=3&start_date=2019-07-21%2011:42:00&end_date=2021-06-21%2011:42:00&previous_close=true&apikey=7477d5d3af13461b8896af80623bb808'
djı='https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=DJI&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&format=JSON&dp=3&start_date=2019-07-21%2011:42:00&end_date=2021-06-21%2011:42:00&previous_close=true&apikey=7477d5d3af13461b8896af80623bb808'
btc='https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=BTC/USD&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&format=JSON&dp=3&start_date=2019-07-21%2011:42:00&end_date=2021-06-21%2011:42:00&apikey=7477d5d3af13461b8896af80623bb808'
xrp='https://api.twelvedata.com/time_series?symbol=XRP/USD&interval=1day&outputsize=1000&format=JSON&dp=3&start_date=2019-07-21%2011:42:00&end_date=2021-06-21%2011:42:00&apikey=7477d5d3af13461b8896af80623bb808'

stocks=[dxy,spx,djı,btc,xrp]

def corrcalc(data):
    for stock in stocks:
        stock=requests.get(stock).json()
        stock=pd.DataFrame(stock['values'],index=[0])
        df={'dxy':str(stock),'spx':str(stock),'djı':str(stock),'btc':str(stock),'xrp':str(stock)}
        df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
        corr_matrix = np.corrcoef(df).round(decimals=2)
        print(corr_matrix)
corrcalc(stocks)
```

I am working with financial data using twelvedata API and tried writing a function calculating correlation of the data but I encounter with this error. What should I do?

Comment: Please provide more information, or even better a Minimum Working Example. What is `data`? Where does the error happen? What is the complete stacktrace? What kind of data are you expecting from the `requests.get()` ?

Comment: I updated, what I mean with data is prices.

Comment: OK, so your problem in that you pass `index=[0]` in your DataFrame. Removing it fixes your issue, but creates new errors later. Your code is really messed up.  `pd.DataFrame(stock['values'])` gives a correct dataframe (492 rows, and columns `datetime/open/high/low/close/volume/previous_close`).  But after that, your codes stops to make sense for me.  `str(stock)`  is just a meaningless string, that you fills in all different columns, and then try to do `corrcoef` on that. Use a debugger or print after each line to see what your operations were, and understand what you are trying to achieve.